# Show columns in specific display order by default in GridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gridview, telerik

I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to have my columns start in a default order(left to right) for all users.

I tried setting them in the `IList<T>` that I use to populate the DataSource but that doesn't work.

Do I have any options besides setting each column manually following the instructions on this page -->[Reordering Columns](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-columns-reordering-columns.html)

Comment: do you mean that you want display the column as you want ?

Comment: left to right.... So I have Col_1, Col_2, Col_3, Col_4 and I want them to be displayed, starting on the left(or index 0) with Col_3, then Col_2, Col_4, Col_1.  Make sense.  I'm NOT talking about Visibility here.

Comment: have you check my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following documentation.

http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/gridview-populating-with-data-tips-when-binding-to-custom-collections.html

You can pretty much define the way you want the columns to look like. Here is the code:

```
radGridView1.MasterTemplate.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Columns.Add(new GridViewTextBoxColumn("Name"));
radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Columns.Add(new GridViewTextBoxColumn("Attributes"));
radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Columns.Add(new GridViewTextBoxColumn("LastAccessTime"));
radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Columns.Add(new GridViewTextBoxColumn("CreationTime"));
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\");
FileSystemInfo[] filesInDirectory = directory.GetFileSystemInfos();
radGridView1.DataSource = filesInDirectory;
```

As you can see, I have set not to autogenerate the columns. Then I define the columns I want. And then just bind the datasource. This will give you the order you want

Do let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm walking on VB.NET and I did something like this ..

```
dgv.Columns(Col4).DisplayIndex = 0
dgv.Columns(Col3).DisplayIndex = 1
dgv.Columns(Col2).DisplayIndex = 2
dgv.Columns(Col1).DisplayIndex = 3
```

in C# you can find it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

Answer (score 0):

The grid will read and create its columns according to the fields in your object:

```
    class MyObj
    {
        public string Column2 { get; set; }
        public int Column1 { get; set; }
    }
```

The above code will first add Column2 and then Column1 in your grid, while the following code will do the opposite:

```
    class MyObj
    {
           public int Column1 { get; set; }
           public string Column2 { get; set; }
    }
```

Same goes for DataTables, it just reads the columns in the order they are.

To reorder them you can use the **Move** method as you already found out.

Comment: you'd think so but it doesn't work that way.  At least not with an IList and RadGridView control.  Thanks though.

Comment: I have tested this in a sample before addressing your question and this is how it behaves on my end.